# JumpStart labs EventManager - incorrect day numbers

Tags: ruby

thanks for reading my question.  I'm working through the EventManager tutorial (http://tutorials.jumpstartlab.com/projects/eventmanager.html#iteration:-day-of-the-week-targeting).

I'm having an issue with my date output.  Here is the method I'm using.

```
def peak_days(day)
  DateTime.strptime(day, '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M').wday
end
```

Later on I'm iterating over each row from the csv file.  The first date from the file is "11/12/08", which I expected to return "3", for Wednesday.  Instead, it returns "1".

```
day = peak_days(row[:regdate])
```

Can anybody tell me why this would be happening?  Here is my complete code for the exercise:

```
require 'csv'
require 'sunlight/congress'
require 'erb'
require 'date'

Sunlight::Congress.api_key = "e179a6973728c4dd3fb1204283aaccb5"

def clean_zipcode(zipcode)
  zipcode.to_s.rjust(5, "0")[0..4]
end

def clean_phone(number)
  clean_number = number.gsub(/[^\d]/, "")
  if clean_number.length == 10
    clean_number
  elsif clean_number.length == 11
    if clean_number.start_with?("1")
      clean_number = number[1..-1]
    else
      clean_number = "0000000000"
    end
  else
    clean_number = "0000000000"
  end
end

def peak_hours(time)
  DateTime.strptime(time, '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M').hour
end

def peak_days(day)
  DateTime.strptime(day, '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M').wday
end

def legislators_by_zipcode(zipcode)
  Sunlight::Congress::Legislator.by_zipcode(zipcode)
end

def save_thank_you_letters(id,form_letter)
  Dir.mkdir("output") unless Dir.exists?("output")

  filename = "output/thanks_#{id}.html"

  File.open(filename,'w') do |file|
    file.puts form_letter
  end
end

puts "EventManager initialized."

contents = CSV.open 'event_attendees.csv', headers: true, header_converters: :symbol

template_letter = File.read "form_letter.erb"
erb_template = ERB.new template_letter

contents.each do |row|

  id = row[0]
  name = row[:first_name]

  zipcode = clean_zipcode(row[:zipcode])

  phone = clean_phone(row[:homephone])

  time = peak_hours(row[:regdate])

  day = peak_days(row[:regdate])

  legislators = legislators_by_zipcode(zipcode)

  form_letter = erb_template.result(binding)

  save_thank_you_letters(id,form_letter)

end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like 1 is the wday of the date in A.D.8.

Try lower case y in the format string:

```
def peak_days(day)
  DateTime.strptime(day, '%m/%d/%y %H:%M').wday
end
```